# how to view/list/select all users' permissions in azure sql database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I seek a T-SQL script that selects all permissions for all users in an Azure SQL Database. In particular I want to generate permission grant/revoke/deny statements for all Views, UDFs and Stored Procs to recreate these permissions in an on-prem database.

Answer (score 1):

One way to list the permissions scripts is to include them with the View, SPROC, and UDF definitions produced via the *Generate Scripts...* context menu option in SSMS. On the *Set Scripting Options* tab of the *Generate and Publish Scripts* wizard, click the *Advanced* button and set the *Script Object-Level Permissions* option to *True*.